# Call a mongoose model inside the socket.on method?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Question, I'm just wondering if I can call a mongoose schema inside the socket.on function? Like

```
socket.on('sendMessage', ({ senderId, receiverId, message }) => {
    const user = getUser(receiverId);
  const accountId = await accountModel.findById(senderId);
    if (user) {
      socket.to(user.socketId).emit('getMessage', {
        accountId,
        message,
      });
    }
  });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably can have it, just make sure the `.on` callback receives an `async` function on it. Something like:

```js
socket.on('sendMessage', async ({ senderId, receiverId, message }) => {
    const user = getUser(receiverId);
    const accountId = await accountModel.findById(senderId);
    if (user) {
      socket.to(user.socketId).emit('getMessage', {
        accountId,
        message,
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: I tried that one but I'm having buffering issue

Comment: what buffering issue?

Comment: Operation `accountmodels.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000

Comment: does this query works outside the socket.io method? Does the db connection working properlu?

Comment: Yeah, i'm using it in my api when fetching a account by id

Comment: I'm using two connection in the backend. First is the connection on my db to mongodb then this socket io

Comment: I had a similiar issue and the solution was to check if the database connection is really working properly. Maybe you can check this issue here and check other alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408618/mongooseerror-operation-users-findone-buffering-timed-out-after-10000ms

Comment: Thanks for the help i saw this thread. my db connection is working file in my api folder. i'm using different port on socket.io folder.

Comment: Sure, but the point is I don't think it is a socket.io issue itself, but some kind of network issue. You can, for example, test with raw tcp socket (as the synthax is similar) and check if the issue persists (to actually make sure is a network issue).