# Why is my commands giving undefined errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

why wont it recognize this code? its confusing me it should recognize it or has something changed in node/discord that I am not aware of? if i use my command  -balance -clear 10 ect it gives diffrent undefined parts like

-balance - ypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send') under the return message.channel.send command

-clear 10 is message.reply is not a function

### This is the error im getting

```
MongoParseError: option usefindandmodify is not supported
    at parseOptions (Roleplay\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:280:15)
    at new MongoClient (\Roleplay\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:62:63)
    at \Roleplay\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:784:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (\Roleplay\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:781:19)
    at \Roleplay\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:343:10
    at \Roleplay\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (\Roleplay\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (\Roleplay\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1181:10) {
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
Bot Is Online
MongooseError: Operation `profilemodels.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (\Roleplay\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
\Roleplay\commands\beg.js:11
        userID: message.author.id,
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at Object.execute (\Roleplay\commands\beg.js:11:32)
    at module.exports (\Roleplay\events\guild\messageCreate.js:58:17)
PS \Roleplay>
```

### this is the code

```
const profileModel = require("../models/profileSchema");
module.exports = {
  name: "beg",
  aliases: [],
  permissions: [],
  description: "beg for gold",
  async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord, profileData) {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1;
    const response = await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        userID: message.author.id,
      },
      {
        $inc: {
          gold: randomNumber,
        },
      }
    );
    return message.channel.send(`${message.author.username}, you begged and received ${randomNumber} **gold**`);
  },
};
```

This is the messageCreate.js

```
require ('dotenv').config();

const cooldowns = new Map();
const profileModel = require("../../models/profileSchema");
 module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
    const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    let profileData;
    try {
      profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
      if (!profileData) {
        let profile = await profileModel.create({
          userID: message.author.id,
          serverID: message.guild.id,
          gold: 1000,
          bank: 0,
        });
        profile.save();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find(a => a.aliasses && a.aliasses.include(cmd));
  
    
    
    

    if(!cooldowns.has(command.name)){
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }

    const current_time = Date.now();
    const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;

    if(time_stamps.has(message.author.id)){
        const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;

        if(current_time < expiration_time){
            const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;

            return message.reply(`Please wait ${time_left.toFixed(1)} more seconds before using ${command.name}`);
        }
    }
    time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
    setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);



    try{
        command.execute(client, args, cmd, message, Discord, profileData);
}catch (err){
    console.log(err);
}
 };
```

Comment: Can we see how you call the command and what all arguments you pass it? It seems like the `message` variable might be something else which might cause these errors

Comment: Like Caladan said, check the file `events\guild\messageCreate.js`, line 58 and check that you are passing the correct arguments. They may not both be in the same order. Correct either the command file or event file.

Comment: I have added the messageCreate.js on the end of my post

Answer (score 0):

Explanations for different errors:

- `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`: The reason for this error is just the order in which you give the arguments for your command. In your `messageCreate.js` file, you are passing the `client` as the first argument while in your command, you are expecting the message to be the first one. You have switched the places for the `client` and `message` parameter.
- `Operation profilemodels.findOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms`: This error happens because you tried to access data from the database before the connection was even established. For more info, you can go here => [MongooseError - Operation users.findOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408618/mongooseerror-operation-users-findone-buffering-timed-out-after-10000ms)
- `option usefindandmodify is not supported error, you are passing in the useFindAndModify`: The reason for this error is the fact that you are passing in the `useFindAndModify` option when you are connection to MongoDB but these options are not supported which causes the error. You can look into this SO question for more info => [MongoParseError: options useCreateIndex, useFindAndModify are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958221/mongoparseerror-options-usecreateindex-usefindandmodify-are-not-supported)