# MongooseError: Operation `teachers.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, next.js

```
//package
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");


//models
const Teacher = require("../client/next-app/models/Teacher");

// Build a server
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

//db connection info
const mongoURL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/studentManageDB";

// CORS middleware
app.use(cors());

// MongoDB connection
mongoose.connect(mongoURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connection established"))
  .catch(error => console.error("MongoDB connection error:", error));


const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDb connection error:"));
db.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB connection established");
});


// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());

///////////////////////// TEACHERS /////////////////////////
// Teacher get route
app.get("/api/teachers", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("Teachers get started");
    const teachers = await Teacher.find();
    console.log("Teachers get finished");
    res.status(200).json(teachers);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Teachers get error:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong", error: error.message });
  }
});


// Teacher signup route
app.post("/api/signup", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { fullname, email, password, fieldOfEducation, termsChecked, photo } = req.body;

    // If the user already exists, return an error
    const existingUser = await Teacher.findOne({ email });
    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "This email is already in use" });
    }

    // Create a new teacher
    const newTeacher = new Teacher({
      fullname,
      email,
      password,
      fieldOfEducation,
      termsChecked,
      photo
    });

    // Save the new teacher to the database
    await newTeacher.save();

    console.log("Teacher signup finished");
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Signup successful" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong", error: error.message });
  }
});

// Teacher login route
app.post("/api/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await Teacher.findOne({ email, password });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
    }

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Login successful", user });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Login error:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong", error: error.message });
  }
});


// Call the server
const server = async () => {
  try {
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Server error:", error);
  }
}

server();
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const teacherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  fullname: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  fieldOfEducation: { type: String, required: true },
  termsChecked: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  photo: { type: String },
});

const Teacher = mongoose.model('Teacher', teacherSchema);

module.exports = Teacher;
```

These are my server.js and teachers model. My connection was working but all of a sudden it started giving this error. I looked through the previous threads but the solutions didn't work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I get the information that the database connection has been made in the server terminal

The complete code is here there are no missing parts

and the error is:

Login error: MongooseError: Operation `teachers.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout. (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\NewMind_Task\client\next-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:186:23)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)

Comment: which mongoose version are you using? did you try the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408618/mongooseerror-operation-users-findone-buffering-timed-out-after-10000ms?rq=2)?